# Shared preferences boolean does not get updated in if-statment

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences

Basically what I wan to achieve is that when a user clicks on a button it disappears and a TextView shows instead. So when the user clicks away from the activity with the button and gets back it still should show the TextView, not the button. To achieve this I used SharedPreferences and a if else statement, but somehow the preferences do not get updated. When the user clicks on the button everything is as expected but when he clicks away and gets back to the activity, it shows the button again which it shouldn't.

I am relatively new to the concept of SharedPreferences, so any help is much appreciated!

Here is my activity:

```
...
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private  boolean premiumPurchased;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_premium_purchase);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String username = user.getDisplayName();

        purchase = findViewById(R.id.card_view_premium_purchase);
        premiumTextView = findViewById(R.id.premium_purchase_success);


        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        if (!premiumPurchased){

            String uid = user.getUid();
            premiumPurchased = mPreferences.getBoolean (uid, true);
            premiumTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            purchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("User").document(username);

                    // Set the "pro membership" in Firestore to true
                    userRef
                            .update("pro membership", true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    premiumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    purchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putBoolean(uid, true);
                                    editor.apply();
                                }
                            })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                                        }
                                    });
                }
            });
        }else if (premiumPurchased) {
            premiumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            purchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
...
```

In the else if statement it shows `premiumPurchased` as always true and I don't now why, I already tried a few variants but it still shows this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the value from `SharedPreferences` first and based on the value `show/hide` content. And also pull out the `onClick` outside `if-else` to keep condition clean.

Try like below:

```
String uid = user.getUid();
mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
premiumPurchased = mPreferences.getBoolean (uid, false); 

if (premiumPurchased) {
    premiumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    purchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);  

} else {
    purchase.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    premiumTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

....

        purchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("User").document(username);

                // Set the "pro membership" in Firestore to true
                userRef
                        .update("pro membership", true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                premiumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                purchase.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean(uid, true);
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                                    }
                                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Kaiser, Did you check this?

Comment: Yes thank you, this works perfectly. In the else statement of yours there is one bracket too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
premiumPurchased = mPreferences.getBoolean (uid, true);
```

Take this line out of if else block. The variable premiumPurchased is created everytime the activity is created and by default JVM will give it the value. To read from sharedPreference you need to read and assign the variable the value before encountring the if-else block.